# Will a stone released from an accelerated train retain the velocity the train had at the instant of release?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, velocity

My books says that since the 2nd law is a local relation, when a stone is released from an accelerated train, there is no horizontal force or acceleration on the stone, if air resistance is neglected. The stone only has vertical force of gravity. Will the stone retain the velocity (or at least a part of it), the train had at the instant the stone was released, due to inertia of motion?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, the stone's horizontal velocity (which will match that of the train's when it is thrown) will be conserved, so long as no horizontal force is acting on it.

If the stone is thrown up while the train is accelerating forwards, then an observer in the train will witness the stone appearing to accelerate backwards in the time that it is in the air.